# Swig directors and smart pointers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, c++11, swig

I have encountered some problems when using Swig trying to wrap smart pointers to director classes in Python. I am aware that the documentation says that the support is somewhat limited, but I would like to know whether my scenario is supported by Swig or not.

In a nutshell, if a director class is extended in Python and passed around as a smart pointer, when the Python object dies the memory area dies. If `__disown__` is used to prevent this, a memory leak occurs (see also http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Using-director-shared-pointer-disown-gt-memory-leak-td11821.html).

Here is a minimal example that shows the problem.

example.h:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace example
{

class ContentBase
{
public:
    ContentBase() {}

    virtual ~ContentBase() {}

    virtual std::string get_name() { return "ContentBase " + m_name; }

    virtual void set_name(const std::string& name) { m_name = name; }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container() {}

    void set_content(std::shared_ptr<ContentBase> content) { m_content = content; }

    std::shared_ptr<ContentBase> get_content() { return m_content; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ContentBase> m_content;
};

} // namespace example

#endif /* EXAMPLE_H */
```

example.i:

```
%module(directors="1") example

%include "std_string.i"
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%shared_ptr(example::ContentBase)
%feature("director") example::ContentBase;

%include "example.h"
```

test_example.py:

```
import pytest

import example as e

class PyContent(e.ContentBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        e.ContentBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = "empty"
        #self.__disown__()

    def get_name(self):
        return "py " + self.name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n

def set_python_content(container):
    content = PyContent()
    content.set_name("content")
    container.set_content(content)

    content2 = container.get_content()
    assert content2.get_name() == "py content"

def test_python_inheritance():
    container = e.Container()
    set_python_content(container)

    content = container.get_content()
    assert content.get_name() == "py content"
```

Is there a way to keep `ContentBase` alive as long as there is at least a Python reference or a shared pointer alive (and without memory leaks)?

NOTE: I am using Swig 3.0.12, but the same behavior occurs even when using the latest version compiled from Github (c44adff7b9f5dc675d7c2dbbf4ea36660c3b1466).

Comment: @burumbum: Are you still interested in this issue? Could you possibly update your question to current Swig-4.0.2?

Comment: We have actually found a workaround that covers our use case. To be honest we are still using 3.0.12 so I do not know whether it is still applicable to 4.0.2

Comment: Could you please post your workaround here ? I have the same issue as you and did not found how to circumvent it ! Many thanks.

Comment: The workaround basically requires (a) defining a "PyContent" class that wraps Python objects that inherit from `ContentBase` and (b) replacing `set_content` and `get_content` with methods that work with raw pointers. If you want I can post a sketch that should hopefully give you an idea. However, I do not recommend our solution, it's quite complicated...